# Why do we use the exponential in the Boltzmann distribution

Tags: exponential-function, monte-carlo, statistical-mechanics

Low effort question incoming. Given a set of states $x_i,i=1,\dots,n$ with energy $0\leq U(x_i)$, we define the probability of a state $x$ as
$$
\pi(x)=\frac{1}{Z_T}e^{-\frac{1}{T} U(x)}
$$
where $Z_T$ is just a normalization constant. According to the Wikipedia this distribution is the maximum entropy distribution on the set of states for a given mean (so I guess you can tune $T$ to get any mean). Then I've seen this in Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstatistics
where they define $\beta=\frac{1}{T}$ and given a distribution $f(\beta)$ of the inverse temperature on $(0,\infty)$ they sort of extend the definition to
$$
\pi(x)=\frac{1}{Z_\beta}\int_{0}^\infty d\beta f(\beta)e^{-\beta U(x)}
$$
I don't really know if this theorem
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein's_theorem_on_monotone_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions)
goes in the direction of
expected value of exponentials implies complete monotonicity.
I have two sort of informal questions:

1. What is it with exponentials and this expected exponentials? What would be lost by picking a function $x<y \Rightarrow f_T(x)<f_T(y)$ and define
   $\pi(x)\propto f_T(U(x))$? Is complete monotonicity somehow playing an important hidden role?
2. Why do people use the Boltzmann distribution for MCMC in the TSP problem for example? Why not any other function that makes a delta at the minimum when $T\rightarrow 0$? Is there some kind of optimal convergence?

Comment: (For this comment, I will use your conventions, taking the reference measure to be counting and a negative in the exponent). Note that in the high temperature limit, the Boltzmann distribution converges to a uniform distribution on the configuration space. In the low temperature limit, it converges to a uniform distribution on the set of minimizers of the energy. In particular, this property of the low temperature limit is very useful, and is due to the behavior of the exponential.